# jar tvf: Top two levels only

Tags: jar

jar tvf prints the contents of a jar

Suppose  only want to print to console the top two levels in my jar

e.g.,

```
application.conf
org/apache
com.mycorp
```

etc

can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No,

but you can get specific lines as follows:

```
jar -tf $PLAY_DEV_HOME/deployment/tools_sirf_server_assembly.jar | grep sirf
```